# Oracle APEX application failing to read data present in database

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am working on an APEX application and am faced with an issue in which data present in the database is not read by the application. Rather, the application reads some of fields from the database and not the rest without throwing any error message.
This small application has a main page that contains tombstone information about work projects we are engaged in and is represented by approximately 30 Oracle items of type ‘Database column' that are the fields of the main project overview table.  This main page also has several interactive reports that allow the users to manipulate data from other related tables like project costs, project deliverables, project recommendations, etc. While the functionality to create/update/delete from these related tables works perfectly, I am still unable make the same  functionality work for the main table and am unable to figure out why as Oracle is not giving me an error message. The changes I submit in the application clearly hit the database as I can see the record updated in the Oracle Object Browser or by querying in SQL commands. I have visually depicted the situation below and thank you in advance for any assistance.

1. Open project number ‘1982’ and populate with dummy data and ‘save’.
   [image]
2. Entered data appears in the main table correctly

[image]

[image]
[image]

3. Open record project number 1982 and observe that only some of the fields are
   shown in the application even though the fields are clearly populated accurately in the underlying table.
   [image]
   [image]

Comment: My first guess would be that you made a change that wasn't committed.  It is also possible that whatever process you have that populates those items is incorrect.

Comment: @JustinCave Don't the images from of the SQL commands indicate the changes were committed to the database? The changes are committed, there is an error in transferring/rendering I believe - probably caused by special characters

Comment: I don't see any commits in your images (note that it is strongly preferred to post text not images in your question).  As I said, it is possible that whatever process you have that populates those items is incorrect

Comment: My first guess would be that the data is there , but the page items that do not show data have different settings from the page items that do have data and that is why the values are not shown. This is apex 5.1 - quite a bit has changed since then... so can't tell you exactly what to look at, but you could create a new form on any table and then compare the settings one by one against a page item that does not show data.

Comment: Note that apex 5.1 is no longer supported.